# Cloudera Navigator Performance evaluation

Tags: performance, cloudera, analysis, cloudera-navigator

I wanted to know about the performance analysis of cloudera Navigator based on below aspects:
1) can i add multiple Cloudera Navigator server installed in a cluster for load balancing.
2) Is there any limit on number of events handled by Navigator Server/Queue. what happened if my queue is flooded with events.

Answer (score 0):

1) Cloudera Navigator is based on Solr, an open source search tool. Solr has the ability to do this load balancing so I believe Cloudera Navigator does too. The tool is a bit new still so I'd assume you might run into a few hiccups when trying to do this, but it should be possible.

2) I believe your only limitation here is the space the metadata stored by Navigator takes up. We ran into an issue with it filling up a small (<2 GB) drive so we simply moved it to a larger drive. We cut and paste the metadata and everything was again searchable through Navigator.